Distinct method ony works when modifying string
I am having an issue with the Linq Distinct Method. I have a List of LocationID's

B A01A
B A01A
A A01A
A A01A
A A01A

As you can see, there are only two distinct values here. However, When they are passed through this code block here
var result = rootObject.OrderLines.Where(orderLine =>
orderLine.OrderAllocations
    .Where(y => y.StatusID != 250) 
    .Select(y => y.LocationID)  
    .Distinct() 
    .Count() == 1);

The count is 1 when in reality it should be 2.
However when I Modify the string with a .Concat() or .Reverse() method like below
var result = rootObject.OrderLines.Where(orderLine =>
orderLine.OrderAllocations
    .Where(y => y.StatusID != 250) 
    .Select(y => y.LocationID.Reverse())  
    .Distinct() 
    .Count() == 1);

the count is correct. not sure what is happening

I suggest you remove the Count part and fetch the results of Distinct, then check whether they locally have exactly the same values. I wouldn't be surprised if non-printable characters or something similar are having an impact. I'd also suggest looking at what query is being generated, and try to reproduce the problem in plain SQL. (That may help you find the bad data, if there is any.)

To me, the fact that a reversed string works suggests that you have whitespace characters at the start of one of your IDs. In SQL, different leading whitespace makes two values different, but different trailing whitespace doesn't.
